# Nesting arbitrary objects in Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble solving a particular problem in Java (which I did not find by search). I do not know how to create a nested lists of objects - with a different type of object/primitive type at the end. For example:

**Note: only an example. I am actually doing this below with something other than Employee, but it serves as simple example.*

I have an array of an object Employee. It contains information on the Employee.

```
public class Employee {
    int age
    int salary
    int yearsWorking
    public Employee () {
        // constructor...
    }
    // Accessors
}
```

What I need to do is organize the Employees by quantiles/percentiles. I have done so by the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.rank.Percentile;
public class EmployeeSort {
    public void main(String args[]) {
        Percentile p = new Percentile();
        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[100];
        // filled employeeArray
        double[] ageArray = new double[100];
        // filled ageArray with ages from employeeArray
        int q = 25; // Percentile cutoff
        for (int i = 1; i*q < 100; i++) {
            // assign percentile cutoff to some array to contain the values
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I have is that I need to organize the Employees first by the percentiles of age, then percentiles of yearsWorking, and finally by percentiles of salary. My Java knowledge is inadequate right now to solve this problem, but the project I was handed was in Java. I am primarily a python guy, so this problem would have been a lot easier in that language. No such luck.

Edit:
So I notice some confusion on whether I need ordering, and some people suggesting use of Comparator. I use Comparator because percentiles requires an ordered list. The problem I am having is how to store the binning of the Employee into their appropriate percentile. To clarify, I need the Employee object binned together into their appropriate percentile by age. Then, within that bin of age, I need to bin all those Employee objects within percentiles for Employee.yearsWorking. Following that, within a given percentile bin of yearsWorking which is within a given percentile bin of Employee.age, I need to create percentile bins of Employee.salary.

Comment: When u say organize, do you mean sort them? can you please elaborate more on how you would like to organize them

Comment: So what you need is a container which will either contain other containers or a list of items?

Comment: In other words, a tree-like structure?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
in place of Arrays.

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();

for (int i = 0, i <= employeeArray.length; i++)
    employeeList.add(employeeArray[i]);
```

Now write down custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public class EmployeeComparatorByAge<Employee>
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        if (o1 != null && o2!= null && o1 instanceof Employee && o2 instanceof Employee )
            return ((Employee)o1).age - ((Employee)o2).age;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can write for other comparisions.

To sort them now, use:

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, new EmployeeComparatorByAge<Employee>());
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out java.util.Comparator<T> (the T in this case would be your Employee type)

You can create different Comparators and use Collections.sortList or Arrays.sort(...) (these methods are pseudo methods - look up the exact versions from the docs)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array use an `ArrayList` to hold your Employees. You can then use `Collections.sort()` to sort that list. There are two versions of sort(), one of which takes a `Comparator` that will allow you to sort in your desired order.

Comment: You can also do this using an array and java.util.Arrays

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this link to understand [Object Ordering in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

The next thing that you want to do is use an ArrayList and add all your employees in this. You would then want to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
/**
  * Add your employee objects to the list
  */


Collections.sort(contacts, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        int returnValue;
        /**
         * Your comparison logic
         */

        return returnValue;
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.sort() with different Comparator implementations as noted above.  Keep in mind that this method (as well as Collections.sort()) operate on the data in place.  So if you need to keep getting at different views of the data, you may want to duplicate the array and sort it different ways, and hold onto each view.

This would be more efficient (CPU-wise) than constantly re-sorting the array.